# Сравнение двух массивов в python(numpy)

Tags: python, массивы

Я имею 2 массива numpy, возможно ли сравнить их поэлементное равенство средствами библиотеки, не перебирая их вручную?

Comment: ответ numpy.array_equal(x1, x2)

Comment: не помещайте ответы в комментарии: если думаете, что нашли решение, [опубликуйте его как ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 6):

Ответ:

```
numpy.array_equal(x1, x2)
```

Comment: `x1 == x2` возвращает boolean массив, который показывает результат сравнения для каждой пары элементов.